# How to fetch data without retrieve to widgets in flutter?

Tags: flutter

In my code I want fetch data to backend without show in ui. Data getting from API, andaslo for that I use model class that same model and API call I used to fetch data and **show** in UI. That's work without any errors.But in this page I want get **doctor_in** vale is true or **false**  from that same model and API call method.

**model class**

```
   class DataDoctor {
  String appId;
  String channelName;
  String receiver_name;
  bool doctor_in;

  DataDoctor(
      {required this.appId,
      required this.channelName,
      required this.receiver_name,
      required this.doctor_in});

  factory DataDoctor.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DataDoctor(
      appId: json['appId'] == null ? null : json['appId'],
      channelName: json['channelName'] == null ? null : json['channelName'],
      receiver_name:
          json['receiver_name'] == null ? null : json['receiver_name'],
      doctor_in: json['doctor_in'] == null ? null : json['doctor_in'],
    );
  }
}
```

using this model I want get doctor_in boolean value
to the **getDoctorActive()** method

**getDoctorActive() method**

```
void getDoctorActive() {
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonData =
        json.decode(jsonDataAsString) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    doctor_in.value = jsonData['doctor_in'].toString();   }
```

**error**

[image]

How to get data without show in UI in flutter?

**API code**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import '../model/appIdModel.dart';


class ApiService {
  loadData(String channelName) async {
    final String url ='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1=$channelName';

    Future<List<Data>> getData() async {
      Response response = await get(Uri.parse(url));
      if (response.statusCode == 2000) {
        Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(response.body);
        List<dynamic> body = json['data'];

        List<Data> datas = body.map((dynamic item) => Data.fromJson(item).toList();
            return datas;
            } else {
            throw ('cannot fetch data');
            }
        }
  }


}
```

**initState**

```
Timer? timer;
  bool doctor_in = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getDoctorActive();
    timer =
        Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 15), (Timer t) => checkDoctorActive());
  }
```

**checkDoctorActive**

```
 Future<void> checkDoctorActive() async {
    if (doctor_in == true) {
      future = client.getData(widget.channelName);
    }
  }
```

**errors**

[image]

**API call**

[image]

Comment: Can you share your api call code?

Comment: okay I will add

Comment: This is API code but api url is not real url is demo

Comment: Ok, how do you call getData()?

Comment: In my code at the initState i call "checkDoctorActive" method in that checking boolean value doctor_active true or false , when open the page it defalut value is false. So in   checkDoctorActive() method call getData() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to periodically fetch data in the background without updating the UI, you can create a class for that purpose, like this

```
class DoctorCheck{
  Future<bool> isDoctorActive(String channelName) async {
    // do the api call here as shown in the line below
    // var jsonResponse = await client.getData(widget.channelName)
    return Data.fromJson(jsonResponse).doctor_in == true;
  }
}
```

And call it wherever you want, like this

`bool isDoctorActive = await DoctorCheck().isDoctorActive(channelName);`

It will return a bool whether the doctor is active or not.

Put it in a function like this

```
Future<void> dr() async { 
  bool isDrActive = await DoctorCheck().isDoctorActive(channelName); 
  setState(() { doctor_in = isDrActive; }); 
}
```

Whenever you call `dr()`, your variable doctor_in will be updated with the latest value of whether doctor is active or not.

Comment: I added as you told. in my code show some errors. I will update my question

Answer (score 1):

From @rrttrr answer with a change

```
class DoctorCheck{
  Future<bool> isDoctorActive(String channelName) async {
    return Data.fromJson(json).doctor_in == true; // Change jsonResponse to json
  }
}
```

Comment: at the ( url) show this error "The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>"

Comment: change it to json

Comment: okay error solve at the API call Thank you so much. DO you know how to solve next error "  bool isDoctorActive =
      await ApiServiceDataDoctor().isDoctorActive(channelName); "

Comment: Please clean the code and produce entire clean updated code. and specifiy the errors. It is confusing